# Is 12 cu. in. LB PVC Conduit large enough to splice 12/2 run?

Tags: electrical

I am running a 20A circuit to the garage and using a LB conduit at a point where my run comes out of the basement and goes underground. I want to run 12/2 NM from the house to this junction box and splice with lose cables that will continue the run to the garage.

This feels like Electric 101 and the box feels big enough. This is why I was surprised when doing Box Fill calculation it appears as if the junction box is not big enough.

In the photo below you see 3 12 AWG wires. Imagine a 12/2 NM comes out of the hole that goes into the house and the standard 3 splices.

- 4 12 awg conductors = 4 x 2.25 = 9 cu.in.
- Volume allowance for all grounds: 1
- 3 Clamps: 3 volume allowance.

This leads to 13 cu.in. **but the box is 12.** Am I double counting something? It just feels strange that a perfectly reasonable looking junction box is not sufficient for this simple use case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you counting clamps? Clamps only count if they are in the box. Clamps that are outside the box don't count. I see 0 countable clamps here. you are also doing something odd with the ground and/or cable clamps. They count one of the wire size, not 1 cubic inch. So you would have 1 for grounds, 4 for conductors terminating in the box (that are not grounds, a total of 5 * 2.25 = 11.25, nary a clamp in sight.

Comment: My bad, I confused the connection nuts with clamps and counted those. 11.25 cu.in. as you showed makes sense. I am just connecting, black to black, white to white, green to green with wire nuts in this box. Sounds like its all good. Thanks,

Comment: @ssm -- is there a reason that the LB looks misaligned from the conduit that's supposed to be coming out the back of it?  Also, what diameter is this conduit, and were you planning to stuff a NM through the conduit coming into the back of this body?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel1 I updated the photo. The original was work in progress without the pipe going into the wall property connected. Yes, NM is coming out of the house. I just had to fish it 5 feet or so with a 90 taking the PVC into the floor system. From there it is just staples to joist as per usual and towards the panel. The pvc conduit is 3/4 inch diameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You don't need a clamp allowance because there are no cableclamps here

There's no need for a clamp allowance here, because that is for *cable* clamps that sit inside a box and anchor the jacket of a cable to the box's entrance, and you don't have anything like that in this scenario.  So, you have 4 2.25 in3 allowances for the 12AWG wires + a fifth for the grounds, which makes 11.25 in3, within the range of this 12 in3 marked body.

Comment: Wouldn't that cable have to be UF-B?

Comment: @JACK considering the cable's terminating in the body, the situation isn't really clear (it'd need to be UF-B if it continued past that point, but many people will terminate NM into outdoor surface-mount boxes even though it isn't the greatest idea)

Comment: I actually stumbled on this searching for information on splicing in a conduit body between a ceiling fan and a down rod.